# Logistic Regression in Python

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, logistic-regression

I'm trying to build a Logistic regression model using numPy and training it on TensorFlow "Getting Started" example: `{x: [1, 2, 3, 4], y: [0, -1, -2, -3]}` using the same learning rate and epochs as the one on tensorFlow example but for some reason it cant learn the correct weight and bias. Any help? I'm new to AI.

Code:

```
# Compute cost and gradient
def propagate(w, b, X, Y):
    m = X.shape[0]
    A = sigmoid(np.multiply(w,X) + b)
    arr = (np.multiply(w,X) + b) - Y
    cost = np.dot(arr, arr)
    cost = np.squeeze(cost)
    dw = 1/m * X.dot((A-Y).T)
    db = 1/m * np.sum(A-Y)

    return {"db": db, "dw": dw}, cost

# Gradient Descnet
def optimize(w, b, X, Y, epochs, learning_rate):
    costs = []

    for i in range(epochs):
        grads, cost = propagate(w, b, X, Y)
        dw = grads['dw']
        db = grads['db']
        w = w - learning_rate * dw
        b = b - learning_rate * db
        if i % 100 == 0:
            costs.append(cost)

    return {"w":w, "b":b}, {"db": db, "dw": dw}, costs
```

Output:

```
w, b, X, Y = np.array([0.3]), -0.3, np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]), np.array([0, -1, -2, -3])

grads, cost = propagate(w, b, X, Y)

print ("dw = " + str(grads["dw"])) # dw = 6.6074129907
print ("db = " + str(grads["db"])) # db = 2.10776208142
print ("cost = " + str(cost))      # cost = 23.66

params, grads, costs = optimize(w, b, X, Y, epochs= 100, learning_rate = 0.01)

print ("w = " + str(params["w"])) # w = [-4.85038348] (supposed to be about -0.9999969)
print ("b = " + str(params["b"])) # b = -1.86763966366 (supposed to be about 0.99999082)
```

Comment: you should tag tensorflow

Comment: Note that the tensorflow example uses linear regression not logistic. The output of the logistic function (sigmoid) is always in the range between 0 and 1 so it can never fit the output y: [0, -1, -2, -3]

Comment: Ahh thanks. I sometimes confuse linear regression with logistic regression and I did forget I was using sigmoid. So whats your suggestion, use another activation function? and ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a linear function as activation for your last layer. 
And it is better to normalize your data to have better results.